# Pressmove in javascript , is there a way to detect the elements the mouse or finger touch moving across?

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, adobe

I'm making a game in animate and i need to detect when mousepress which objects i'm moving on and which is out
pressmove event gives me only the target name of the first object i pressed
is there such a way to detect every element
or a way to detect when pressmove is outside some element?